# Getting name error: name Self is not defined while using Twisted in Python. How to remove this error?

Tags: python

```
def mention_notifier(self):
    print self.stat_old


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    self.stat_old = Set([])
    l = task.LoopingCall(mention_notifier).start(timeout)
```

This is the basic skeleton of my code. I want stat_old to be a global variable that doesn't get re intialized every time I call mention_notifier. Thus, I did something like this. But got this error of 'self' not defined. Any clues how to go about this?

Comment: `self` only makes sense when you're writing a class in Python. Are you intending to write a class that allows you to instantiate an object? Or will this only ever be a "classless" script?

Comment: @sarnold -- using the name `self` as a variable is legal in python -- It's just frowned upon when it isn't inside a class ...  That (unconventional) variable name shouldn't be causing any problems here (other than making the script more difficult to understand ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Twisted, but from looking at the [docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html), something like this might work:

```
def mention_notifier(self):
    print self.stat_old

class Namespace(object): 
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    self=Namespace()
    self.stat_old = Set([])
    l = task.LoopingCall(mention_notifier,self).start(timeout)
```

Of course, here the variable name `self` should probably be changed to something else -- by convention `self` is typically used inside of classes to reference the instance of the class in a method call ...

It looks like `LoopingCall` can be given arguments to be passed along to the function (in this case, the Namespace object `self` is passed).  Then inside the function, "self" is modified (as long as you don't do something like `self=...` inside the function, you're golden -- `self.attribute=...` is completely fine)